# Last login of user not updated in database

Tags: php, authentication

I inserted a last_login field inside my user table and put the $update query in my doLogin.php but it does not update the timestamp in the database when the user logs in. Is there anything that I am missing?

```
        $update = "UPDATE `user` SET last_login = NOW() WHERE  id='user_id'";
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email_address'];
        $_SESSION['gender'] = $row['gender_id'];
        $_SESSION['role_id'] = $row['role_id'];
        $msg1 = $_SESSION['username'];
        $msg2 = "Gender: " . $_SESSION['gender'] . "<br/>";
        $msg3 = "Email: " . $_SESSION['email'] . "<br/>";
        $msg .= "You are logged in as " . $_SESSION['role_type'] . "<br/>";
```

Comment: you are missing mysqi_query($update);

Comment: You should get an error like `$result not found`. Think you indeed forgot to `mysqli_query()`

Answer (score 1):

see added `mysqli_query($update);` next to your query

```
         $update = "UPDATE `user` SET last_login = NOW() WHERE  id='user_id'";
        mysqli_query($update);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email_address'];
        $_SESSION['gender'] = $row['gender_id'];
        $_SESSION['role_id'] = $row['role_id'];
        $msg1 = $_SESSION['username'];
        $msg2 = "Gender: " . $_SESSION['gender'] . "<br/>";
        $msg3 = "Email: " . $_SESSION['email'] . "<br/>";
        $msg .= "You are logged in as " . $_SESSION['role_type'] . "<br/>";
```